# how can I tell compton versus coherent scatter apart?

Tags: electrons, atoms, radioactivity, electromagnetic-radiation, neutrons

I am trying to get a better understanding of compton and coherent scatting, along with all the other interactions. It has seemed like a lot to memorize and I am trying to find ways to more easily understand them and tell them apart when being asked questions. I was reading today and I think I may have figured out a way to tell them apart but want to make sure my thought process is correct. Here is what I am thinking:

If I can remember that with coherent scatter, the ejected particle has to be in a ground state. which I think of something that needs to  be groudned so it is safe for use and will not cause electrical problems, meaning it has to be "neutral". So coherent ejects something that has to be neutral, or not charged. that means it cant be an electron or proton, therefore its a neutron? and it would make sence because the incoming xray in coherent colides with the nucleus where neutrons can be found. the scattered neutron would be an xray, which again is neutral and like a gamma ray except for its origin, being the nucleus. Now for compton, the incoming photon, ill say it is a xray to be specific, interacts with an electron that is loosly bound/valence electron, which has a negative charge. so really, in coherent, a neutral particle is released. in compton, it is a charged particle?
also with compton, is this only happening within a body?

edit: I read somewher else that in coherent, a photon witht the same energy can be scatterd.. but if it is ground state wouldnt it have no charge? therefor how would it have the same energy as the incoming photon? im confused all over again.

Comment: This is not a question of chemistry. The Compton scattering belongs to physics, The Compton effect is one of the three sorts of interaction happening when electromagnetic radiation interacts with matter, without producing any chemical reaction.